# Not getting right output for natural log formula

Tags: java, probability

I'm trying to get my program to out the first 500 values for this formula: -12*ln(1-x) where x is the return of double next(). I don't know what I'm doing wrong because I can't get the right output. The random number uses this formula x(i+1) = (a * x(i) + c) mod k

```
public class myRnd {
    // Linear values for x(i+1) = (a * x(i) + c) % k 
    final static int a = 7893;
    final static int c = 3517;
    final static int k = 8192;

    // Current value for returning
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    public myRnd() {
        // Constructor simply sets value to half of k
        x = (125*k) /1024;
        //y = (125*k) /1024;
    }

    double next() {
        // Calculate next value in sequence 
        x = (a * x + c) % k; 

        // Return its 0 to 1 value 
        return (double)x / k;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int situation;
        double sec_answer;
        // Create a new myRnd instance
        myRnd r = new myRnd();
        // Output 53 random numbers from it     
        for (int i = 0; i < 53; i++) {
            System.out.println (r.next());
        }
        System.out.println("random variable");
        for(int b = 0; b < 500; b++){
            sec_answer = (-12)*Math.log(1- r.next());
            System.out.println(sec_answer);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What are the first 5 values to output that you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose these are the first 5 values you're expecting from your program in each loop!

```
0.9302978515625
0.270263671875
0.6204833984375
0.90478515625
0.8985595703125

random variable
31.962289651479345
3.78086405322487
11.626283246646423
28.21943313114782
27.45940262908609
```

In your `main` method you have only one instance of the class:

```
// Create a new myRnd instance
myRnd r = new myRnd();
```

This initialization is propagated to both `for` loops.

Simple Solution: Add another instance / initialization of `myRnd` for the second `for` loop, as an example you could reuse the same variable as `r = new myRnd();` before the second loop.